# For loop always runs 2 times before it stops

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to put a very basic math program together.
The below function has worked previously, but right now the for loop always runs 2 full iterations before the function stops.

It should only run 10 times.

I tried several combinations of indentation and for / while loops as well as range and xrange.

It makes 19 iterations.

```py
def gameADD():

    a = 1
    b = 50
    error = 0
    correct = 0
    myguess = 0
    x = 0
    for x in range(0, 10):
        print "for loop",x            
        num1 = random.randint(a, b)
        num2 = random.randint(a, b)
        result = (num1 + num2)

        print "  ",num1
        print "+ ",num2
        print "___________"
        print " "
        myguess = input('Hvad er Resultatet?:  ')

        if myguess != result:
            print
            "Det er forkert"
            print
            "KOM IGEN MESTER"
            error = error + 1
            print
            "forkert times", x

        if myguess == result:
            print
            "__"
            print
            "GODT!!! DET ER RIGTIG"
            print
            result, " er korrekt"
            print
            "Du har lavet ", error, " fejl."
            correct = correct + 1
            print
            "Du har lavet ", correct, " rigtig."
            print
            "korrekt times", x


        x = x + 1
        return error
```

Code triggering the function:

```
pick=input('Hvad vil du lave? :')



    if pick == 1:
        os.system('clear') 
        start = time.time()
        gameADD()
        end = time.time()
        calctime = end-start
        print (calctime)," sekunder"
        #insert new data after each round
        con = lite.connect('math.db')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            user = username
            ttime = calctime
            errors = gameADD()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO stats VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);",[user,"1",ttime,errors])            

        raw_input('Tryk ENTER for at komme til hovedmenu....')
        os.system('clear')
```

Comment: It's difficult to help when your code formatting is broken. Also try to break it down into the minimal code that reproduces the error. This might make you debug the error yourself, but also makes it simpler for others to help you.

Comment: Perhaps use the debugger?

Comment: How do you trigger `gameADD()` function? Maybe there's something wrong with the way you trigger the function.

Comment: Could you paste the code that triggers `gameADD()` function?

Comment: I have added the code which triggers the function.

Comment: You are calling `gameADD` twice.

Comment: ahhhhh.... is it when I try to get the errors var from gameADD here:
errors = gameADD()

Comment: YES GUYS - thanks all for the quick replys. Andreas Deak pointed me in the right direction. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Here's the correct version (I have marked the places where I made changes):

```
def gameADD():
    a = 1
    b = 50
    error = 0
    correct = 0
    myguess = 0
    x = 0  # <<-- comment or remove this line
    for x in range(0, 10):
        print "for loop",x            
        num1 = random.randint(a, b)
        num2 = random.randint(a, b)
        result = (num1 + num2)

        print "  ",num1
        print "+ ",num2
        print "___________"
        print " "
        myguess = input('Hvad er Resultatet?:  ')

        if myguess != result:
            print
            "Det er forkert"
            print
            "KOM IGEN MESTER"
            error = error + 1
            print
            "forkert times", x

        if myguess == result:
            print
            "__"
            print
            "GODT!!! DET ER RIGTIG"
            print
            result, " er korrekt"
            print
            "Du har lavet ", error, " fejl."
            correct = correct + 1
            print
            "Du har lavet ", correct, " rigtig."
            print
            "korrekt times", x


        #x = x + 1 # <<-- comment or remove this line
    return error   # <<-- indented to the left
```

Here's the result (runs 10 times as it should):

```
>>> gameADD()
for loop 0
   5
+  28
___________

Hvad er Resultatet?:  4



for loop 1
   12
+  25
___________

Hvad er Resultatet?:  5



for loop 2
   25
+  10
___________

Hvad er Resultatet?:  6



for loop 3
   9
+  12
___________

Hvad er Resultatet?:  4



for loop 4
   44
+  32
___________

Hvad er Resultatet?:  5



for loop 5
   31
+  49
___________

Hvad er Resultatet?:  6



for loop 6
   12
+  45
___________

Hvad er Resultatet?:  4



for loop 7
   12
+  49
___________

Hvad er Resultatet?:  3



for loop 8
   18
+  22
___________

Hvad er Resultatet?:  2



for loop 9
   13
+  10
___________

Hvad er Resultatet?:  3



10
>>>
```

Comment: runs 19 times as well

Comment: @valleyoftears I have added the results of the test run. It runs 10 times as it should.

Answer (score -1):

You've used a for loop but then added conditions as if you're using a while loop. The for loop handles the x = x +1 and the x=0 parts itself so you don't need those.

The for loop and the x=x+1 are both adding 1 to x.

```
def gameADD():
    a = 1
    b = 50
    error = 0
    correct = 0
    myguess = 0
    for x in range(0, 10):
        print "for loop",x            
        num1 = random.randint(a, b)
        num2 = random.randint(a, b)
        result = (num1 + num2)

        print "  ",num1
        print "+ ",num2
        print "___________"
        print " "
        myguess = input('Hvad er Resultatet?:  ')

        if myguess != result:
            print
            "Det er forkert"
            print
            "KOM IGEN MESTER"
            error = error + 1
            print
            "forkert times", x

        if myguess == result:
            print
            "__"
            print
            "GODT!!! DET ER RIGTIG"
            print
            result, " er korrekt"
            print
            "Du har lavet ", error, " fejl."
            correct = correct + 1
            print
            "Du har lavet ", correct, " rigtig."
            print
            "korrekt times", x


    return error
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I have made the suggested changes. The for loop still iterates 19 times

Comment: @valleyoftears When I ran it it only ran for 10. Saw the reason in the way you're triggering it though. If you run it twice it will run for longer :P